# Images displayed with same size as taken?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiimageview

How can i set the content mode of UIImageView to display image as the size as taken like below? to display them as the same logic of Yelp.

[image: Images displayed with same size as taken]

Answer (score 0):

You will need to reference the w/h of the imag.
Somthing like this:

UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImageName.png"];
UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, myImage.size.width, myImage.size.height)];

I don't have XCode open at the moment but the syntax should be similar to this.

Comment: i don't want to set the UIImageView as the same size of UIImage. what i want is to resize the UIImage to be perfectly displayed on the UIImageview like the Yelp app

Answer (score 0):

Set the content mode of imageview as `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`